# PHP - MySql rowCount() problem, not list usernames

Tags: php, mysql

I want to list people with the same username, but i had a problem, i didnt fix it, can you help? please.

I get this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlinj\index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlinj\index.php on line 19

this is my code

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Kişi Gir: <input type="text" name="isim" id="">
    <button type="submit" name="ara">ARA</button>
</form>

<?php

$db=new PDO("mysql:host:localhost;dbname=sqlinj","root","hasan1994");

if(isset($_POST['ara'])){
    $name = $_POST['isim'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM uyeler WHERE isim like '%$name%'";
    $run=$db->query($sql);

    if($run->rowCount()){
        
        foreach($run as $row){ 
?>
            <p><?php echo $row['isim']; ?></p>
<?php
        }
    }else{
        echo "Böyle biri bulunmamakta";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: This normally means the query failed, or the connection. I notice you dont check thatthe connection actually worked

Comment: this query is working in phpMyAdmin, this code example for SQL Injection, i wanna list users

Comment: Add these 2 lines after the connect `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);`